# show option Scale Display to Real Size

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am working with the emulator Samsung Galaxy Tab, and I would climb to 7-inch screen I've seen in many places that when you start the avd it shows an option to do this but I do not quit and the emulator is running in default mode , I can do?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new AVD follow these instructions: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html

Make sure you select the resolution you want in **Skin** and the density in **Hardware**.

The Galaxy Tab will be 600x1024 at 171 dpi.

Then, in Eclipse, select Run Configurations and either choose your target or select "manual" to be asked every time.

Edit: BTW, maybe you were asking about scaling the dpi to match your screen: [How to see Samsung galaxy Tab Emulator in Full size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583943/how-to-see-samsung-galaxy-tab-emulator-in-full-size)

If you do not know the pixel density of your monitor, click the small button `?` next to the **Monitor dpi** text field to let the AVD manager fill it for you.

Comment: @jose check the answer now to see how to fill your monitor dpi value